# Get everything except match in javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url, replace

I have the following regex to get the first part after a url:

```
^http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/([a-zA-Z-_.%]+).*$
```

It matches **test** in the below urls:

> foo.com
>   http://foo.com
>   http://foo.com/**test**
>   http://foo.com/**test**/
>   http://foo.com/**test**?bar

What I'm now trying to do is recreate the same url, but replace **test** with a different value. Either by taking the parts before and after the match or reversing the result.

I'm sure there's a regexy way of doing this, but I'm unable to find out how to do so.

Comment: What you said sounds good, put capture groups around it like thus `^(http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/)[a-zA-Z-_.%]+(.*)$`, replace with `$1newtest$2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capturing group for part before `/test` and use it as back-reference in replacement:

```
var re = /^(https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/)[^?\/]+/gmi; 
var subst = '$1foobar'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

`[^?\/]+` will match text before next `/` or `?` after domain name in URL. As your original regex it also assumes that URLs start with `http://` or `https://`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW9iI7/1)